# Xamarin Forms Markup Extension Binding Local Image Url

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, markup-extensions

I'm trying to bind the imageurl of an object in Xamarin forms xaml. It's an item in a stacklayout, so a hardcoded url would not work. The embeddedimage custom markup works for hardcoded images, but not for the same string located in the ImageUrl string variable. Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
<Image Source="{local:EmbeddedImage {x:Binding ImageUrl}}"/>
```

Comment: Why not just `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>` ?

Comment: That doesn't work for local images. Hence the need for the EmbeddedImage custom markup

Comment: If you use ffimageloading it works